# Plugin is called hundred of times in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

```
app.directive('tooltip_plugin_as_example', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
       $(element).tooltip();
       console.log("this is called");
    }
  };
});

<div class="someclass">
    <ul>
        <li tooltip_plugin_as_example ng-repeat="item in iCtrl">{{item.name}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

`this is called` happens hundreds of times when a new tab is clicked and a new page is loaded. I want it to happen just once, ideally, when the last item is loaded. Is it possible? I am thinking of setting interval, and calling this plugin once a second for example, but obviously, that would be a horrible practice...

Comment: May be you need to call the `.tooltip()` on a parent element `ul`?

Comment: @runTarm hm... how exactly..?

Comment: I'm understanding that you don't want to call `.tooltip()` multiple times on every `li` elements. But you want to call the `.tooltip()` once after the `ng-repeat` finished rendering all the `li` elements. Is that right?

Comment: @runTarm Yes that's exactly right!

Comment: What is the structure of iCtrl?

Answer (score 2):

You're not acting upon any dom event, so "this is called" will log for every instance that's in existence.

Perhaps try this, this will run only when the directive is clicked.

```
app.directive('tooltip_plugin_as_example', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
       element.bind('click',function(){
       //your code
      });

    }
  };
});
```

If I've missunderstood could you provide a better explanation with a jsfiddle?

Comment: Thanks for replying. It's a nice solution, however, the very first time the item is clicked, tooltip won't work (because it wasn't initialised). It starts working only when the item is clicked the second, third etc. time

Comment: Is a jsfiddle out of the question? I feel i'll be of more help if I can see what you're trying to do.

Comment: every li has a tooltip.

Comment: found an example: http://jsfiddle.net/TH87t/470/. Check console, it happens 9 times instead of 1.

Comment: but it should happen 9 times, because there are 9 elements which need the toolbar...

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `.tooltip()` from jqueryui.

It seems you don't have to worry about when the last `li` element has been rendered or the `li` elements are being added/removed.

Just calling `.tooltip()` once on a parent element and it should works. No need to call it again when new elements are added.

You could write a simple directive to call the `.tooltip()`:

```
.directive('tooltip', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element) {
      element.tooltip();
    }
  };
})
```

and place it on the parent element:

```
<ul tooltip>
  <li ng-repeat="item in iCtrl" title="{{item.name}}">{{item.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

or if you want the tooltip for an entire page, you could just calling this once.

```
$document.tooltip();
```

**Example Plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/qNQFnoW4uRzKmEoIH81l?p=preview

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the plugin you're using and the scope you want to apply (on a section of a page or on whole page,...)

1) If your plugin requires you to call it on every element with **different parameters**, it's not a problem using it like in your code, just remember to cleanup to avoid leaking:

```
app.directive('tooltip_plugin_as_example', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
       element.tooltip(); //don't need to wrap inside $()

       scope.$on("$destroy",function(){
          //cleanup your tooltip here. 
          //Example code with jQuery tooltip:
          //element.tooltip("destroy");
       }
    }
  };
});
```

When your collection changes with some items removed, `ng-repeat` will destroy the scopes of these items and `$destroy` events are fired on these scopes allowing to cleanup before angular removes them from the DOM.

2) If your plugin could be called on a parent element to apply **the same** behavior to all its children. You could just use it like @runTarm's answer. Also remember to cleanup to avoid leaking.

Answer (score 1):

Found out an answer (not sure if it's the best, but it works well)

```
app.directive('tooltip_plugin_as_example', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
       if (scope.$last)
       {
         $('.elementClass').tooltip(); 
         console.log("happens once");
       }
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: This works as long as your `iCtrl` collection won't changed or only get appended. if something has been inserted in the middle of the collection later, the `.tooltip()` will not be called.

Comment: @runTarm Hm, not sure if I understand why? The whole list will be reiterated again once a new item appears in the collection, and the last item will still be the same?

Comment: Usually, the `ng-repeat` is smart enough to re-use the existing elements, so the last element may not get re-compiled. For example: http://plnkr.co/edit/5t8qscOWfAS6YGOSpKHw?p=preview

Comment: @runTarm Interesting! Although in my application items will always be appended, what would your solution be if it wasn't the case?

Comment: I couldn't think of any elegant solution either. The best in my mind right now is to use `scope.$watchCollection()` over the `iCtrl` directly combined with `$timeout`.

Comment: @runTarm Could you maybe give an example and add an answer?

Comment: Are you using tooltip from jqueryui?

Answer (score 1):

Use `compile` function instead of `link` function in your directive to avoid these 100's of calls. ng-repeat will take the element already compiled by cloning.

According to AngularJS documentation :-

> Some directives such as ng-repeat clone DOM elements once for each
>   item in a collection. Having a compile and link phase improves
>   performance since the cloned template only needs to be compiled once,
>   and then linked once for each clone instance.

You will get performance benefit of having executed compiled that code only once when using compile function on an ng-repeat.

If you are using `tooltip()` from `jQueryUI`:

`tooltip()` plugin from `jQueryUI` will add listeners etc which will also get cloned however I might suggest using `tooltip` directive from `Angular UI Bootstrap`  project which will ensure proper destruction of the listeners.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check for the last element from ng-repeat you can do it like this:

```
app.directive('tooltipPluginAsExample', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var isLast = attrs.tooltipPluginAsExample;

        if (isLast == 'true') {
            console.log('last element!');
        }
    }
  };
});
```

Inside html you need to use $last variable provided by ng-repeat directive (doc: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat):

```
<div ng-controller="ItemCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li tooltip-plugin-as-example="{{$last}}" ng-repeat="item in iCtrl">{{item.name}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/nzuru5a9/4/

Answer (score 1):

You just need to check the ngRepeat `$last` property in your directive

```
app.directive('tooltip', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      if(scope.$last) {
        //$(element).tooltip();
        console.log("this is called for index:");
        console.log(scope.$index); // check for last index of ngRepeat
      }
    }
  };
});
```

Working JSBin using `$index` to check that it's called only on the last element: http://jsbin.com/pavefe/1/